# How to match a String having metacharacters using regex matches function in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching, metacharacters

What could be the regular expression to match below String

```
String str = "<Element>\r\n <Sub>regular</Sub></Element>";
```

There is a

```
carriage return "\r", new line character "\n" and a space after <Element>.
```

My code is as below

```
if(str.matches("<Element>([\\s])<Sub>(.*)"))
{
     System.out.println("Matches");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "dot matches newline" switch:

```
if (str.matches("(?s)<Element>\\s*<Sub>(.*)"))
```

With the switch turned on, `\s` will match newline characters.

I slso fixed your regex, removing two sets of redundant brackets, and adding the crucial `*` after the whitespace regex.

Comment: @Bohemain : As I mentioned, I have already tried using ([\\s]) is to match newline and carriage return. It does not work.

Comment: @Suvasis You tried with `[\\s]`, but you didn't provide a cardinality. In your regex, replace `[\\s]` by `\\s+` or `\\s*` (brackets are useless in this case).